# Why Ordering of array of denominations is important in Coin Change

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, coin-change

Please see the solution of Minimum Coin Change problem in the below link

http://techieme.in/minimum-number-of-coins/

Here the author taken an assumption that

> The array of denominations is in ascending order.

**My question is that why ordering of array of denominations is important.**

Similar Assumption is taken in the below link too
*(Please Note here the author is solving distinct ways coin change can be made not minimum coin change)*

http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Coin_Change

> now with the restriction that S1 < S2 < ... < S(M), our solutions can
>   be constructed in non-decreasing order

So suppose if my array of denominations is unordered will i get wrong number of ways in which coin change can be made?.

Comment: In the problem, it makes no sense to talk about ordering. But a specific implementation may require the input to be sorted. But which specific implementation have you concerns about the ordering?

Comment: Yes that is exactly my question. Which specific implementation may require the input to be sorted. The algorithmist and techieme both ask input to be sorted which I don't think is anyway required

Answer (score 1):

**My question is that why ordering of array of denominations is important.**

I think, the order for Both solution is not important. If you implemented the solution, the disordered of coin array gives the same answer.

Comment: Yes i implemented and got the same answers, but my test cases may not be exhaustive.

Comment: @veritas I know, you want to know why it's not important. But it is very hard(I know why, you can trust me) to give a simple explanation... You need learn DP hard and understand it completely. Then You could try to prove it by yourself... That's the way to learn algorithm...